# Can a concrete slab with a 6 inch deep footer support a wall made of 8"x8"x16" concrete blocks that is 8 ft high?

Tags: concrete, masonry, slab

Slab is reinforced with 1/2inch rebar. The footer is about 9 inches wide. This is located in Atlanta, GA. I am no soil expert, but there seemed to be a fair amount of clay in the dirt.

Underneath the slab is a thin layer of gravel.

Comment: Also, if there's anything beneath the concrete—direct on soil, or gravel base?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the soil beneath it, and how wide it is (thus, the soil loading applied to that soil beneath it.)

Typical soils have loadings ranging from 2000-5000 PSF. (pounds per square foot)

The "National Concrete Masonry Association" gives [weights per square foot of 8" CMU wall](https://ncma.org/resource/concrete-masonry-wall-weights/) ranging from 25-86 lbs per square foot of wall, depending on concrete density and extent of grouting the wall (filling the cores.)

So each linear foot of 8 foot tall wall (8 square feet) would range between 200 and 688 lbs. That suggests an upper limit of roughly 1032 PSF for loading on the base area (2/3ds of a square foot) of the wall. At roughly half the typical number given for clay, silty clay, and loam soils of 2000 PSF, should be safe. The additional inch of footer width (3/4 of a square foot) lowers the maximum loading to 917 PSF (or 267 PSF for the lightest version of the wall given in the linked chart.)

Answer (score 0):

A 9" wide footer is too narrow for a 8" wide wall, which must be at least 12" but you need to look up the value in the correct table, depending on soil type.  Going double the wall width (16") is a common rule of thumb.